# Odoo. Dropdown with limits

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have some One2Many field in my model. I set **limit = 5** for **tree** element in view. But how I can change list with possible values(80-200-500 etc.) to my custom list(for example: 10-15-etc.)?

[image]

Here my xml:

```
<!-- 
     info about view: 
     <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_my_id_employee_form">
        <field name="name">hr.employee.property.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
-->
<field name="adaptation_result_ids">
    <tree default_order="date desc" limit="5">
        <field name="name"/>
        <field name="date"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Maybe it is possible using **Window Actions** in settings?

[image]

I tried different ways but all in vain. 
Can you help with my problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I dont understand your question, you mean restricting the domain of the one2many?, in that case, restricting the domain to what parametter?. If im in the right direction, the best case would be another field in your adaptation result object (like a boolean one) to difference, and then, add a domain filter in the one2many

Comment: I need just change possible values for dropdown(for specific fields in view). `adaptation_result_ids` - it is One2Many field. And I need set my list for possible values only for this _tree_ element. It is possible?

Comment: Yes, but lets suppose that you have 5 items: 200, 300, 500, 1000 and 2500, and you want to show 200, 300, and 500. Whats the difference between the ones that you want to show that the ones that you dont want to show (1000 - 2500)?

Comment: I need to show 10-15 and that's all. It is not comfortable use limit more that 20 in form with many fields. Moreover, the last 20-40 records most important records. Other records it is just for history.

Comment: Can you explain your whole scenario, its too confusing.

Comment: @010100100110111101101110011 I have dropdown with values like on first screen. I need change values 80-200-500 etc. to 10-15 only for current view that's all. Can you help me?

Comment: you need to do this with python, where is the code?

Comment: @maazza I think this is configurable using xml or systems settings. Maybe using xpath. I really do not have any idea.

Comment: you may have better luck there https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-create-dropdown-list-in-a-custom-module-and-the-values-for-dropdownlist-fetches-from-database-82670

Comment: @maazza that's not what I need. It is dropdown for field of model. But I need change dropdown for **tree** element of view. The system has indeed just a few examples and small 
community. Any non-standard tasks - it is dancing with a tambourine (((

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list_view.js

```
render_pager: function($node) {
//...
this.$pager
//...
.find('.oe_list_pager_state')
    .click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var $this = $(this);

        var $select = $('<select>')
            .appendTo($this.empty())
            .click(function (e) {e.stopPropagation();})
            .append('<option value="80">80</option>' +
                '<option value="200">200</option>' +
                '<option value="500">500</option>' +
                '<option value="2000">2000</option>' +
                '<option value="NaN">' + _t("Unlimited") + '</option>')
            .change(function () {
                var val = parseInt($select.val(), 10);
                self._limit = (isNaN(val) ? null : val);
                self.page = 0;
                self.reload_content();
            }).blur(function() {
                $(this).trigger('change');
            })
            .val(self._limit || 'NaN');
        });
//...
}
```

/my_module/template.xml

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend_tree_pager" name="tree pager" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="//script[@src='/web/static/src/js/views/list_view.js']" position="replace">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_module/static/src/js/views/list_view.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

/my_module/static/src/js/views/list_view.js

```
// TODO code
```